# What do two parentheses after a variable signify?

Tags: c++, constructor, parentheses

I have something like this in one method

```
    autoPtr<LESModel> LESModel::New   
 95 (
 96  const volVectorField& U,
 97  const surfaceScalarField& phi,
 98  transportModel& transport,
 99  const word& turbulenceModelName
100 )
101 {
     ...
122  dictionaryConstructorTable::iterator cstrIter =                       
123  dictionaryConstructorTablePtr_->find(modelType);
     ...
143  return autoPtr<LESModel>      
144  (
145  cstrIter()(U, phi, transport, turbulenceModelName)
146  ); 
147  }
```

If I am right `cstrIter` is a variable of class `dictionaryConstructorTable::iterator` (could not find this class though) and beginning with line 143 the constructor `autoPtr<LesModel>` is called and the result returned. The parentheses after the constructor `autoPtr<LESModel>` therefore should be parameters and since cstrIter is a variable I am wondering what the two parentheses after the variable mean. Perhaps I am misreading something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ supports 'operator overloading', meaning you can define types that support syntax like `a + b`. This works by defining functions with names such as `operator+`. When an overloadable operator is used with a user defined type C++ looks for functions with these special names and, if a suitable function is found, treats the operator as a function call to the function.

One of the operators that one can overload is the function call operator. A member function named `operator()` will be called when you use an object name as though it's a function:

```
struct S {
  void operator() (void) {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  S s;
  s(); // prints "Hello, World!\n"
}
```

It looks like `dictionaryConstructorTable::iterator` overloads the function call operator and returns some type that also overloads the  function call operator (or just uses the built-in operator).

Replacing the use of the function call operator with normal member functions may make it clearer what's happening:

```
return autoPtr<LESModel>( cstrIter.foo().bar(U, phi, transport, turbulenceModelName));
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like OpenFOAM, which has its own hash table implementation.

If you look in src/OpenFoam/containers/HashTable/HashTable/HashTable.H, line 454 (at least in my copy), you'll find that `iterator` overloads `operator()` and `operator*` to return a reference to the iterator's currently referenced value.

To clarify a little, C++ allows you to overload [many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++) of the operators you use to provide domain-specific functionality. This allows for, say, `vector.add(otherVector)` to use the "obvious" syntactic sugar of `vector + otherVector` instead. The downside is that what is obvious is not always so obvious, as this question demonstrates.

Answer (score 1):

This construction

```
cstrIter()(U, phi, transport, turbulenceModelName)
```

means that at first a temporary object of type cstrIter is created using the default constructor

```
cstrIter()
```

And after that the function call operator is used for this object

```
cstrIter()(U, phi, transport, turbulenceModelName)
```

That it would be more clear you could rewrite the expression the following way

```
cstrIter obj;
obj(U, phi, transport, turbulenceModelName);
```